# Formula excel displays first name or last name by code

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

can you help me? i get problem in my homework. I don't know what formula is used in USERNAME if S code then takes first name from NAME and if code K then takes last name. Thank you
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzQV7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(MID(A2,4,1)="S",LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2)-1),MID(B2,FIND(" ",B2)+1,9999))
```

[image]

*(this assumes that **K/S** is always in the fourth position)*

Comment: it's work thank you. may I ask what is the meaning of + 1.9999?

Comment: is there a simpler way? @Gary's Student

Comment: @UcupRahmat  The ***+1*** starts the capture one character **past** the space................... the ***9999*** is the maximum number of characters to be captured.

Answer (score 0):

Use below formula to identify which letter in the cell

IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("S",A2)),Yes,No)

To identify the first name refer below code

LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2,1)-1)

This is for Last name = RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND(" ",B2,1))

By all these combination you will get the below code

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("S",A2)), LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2,1)-1), RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND(" ",B2,1)))

I hope it is useful for you

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has anther way to parse the first and last name.

```
=IF(MID(A2,4,1)="S",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",REPT(" ",99)),99)),TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",REPT(" ",99)),99)))
```